# How to find nearest neighbors of a point and the other point that isn't nearest neighbors removed?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a task to find the nearest neighbors of some points, and remove other points which aren't the nearest neighbors. This task is like under sampling problem.

Code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import spatial

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
majority = data.loc[data['class']==0]
minority = data.loc[data['class']==1]

majority_points=majority.drop('class', axis=1)
minority_points=minority.drop('class', axis=1)

all_data = pd.concat([majority,minority])

data_points = all_data.drop('class', axis=1)
# print(data_points)

majority_points=np.array(majority_points)
print (majority_points)
minority_points =np.array(minority_points)
print (minority_points)
    #result
    [[1 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [1 4]
 [1 5]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]
 [2 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 1]
 [3 2]
 [3 5]
 [4 1]
 [4 4]
 [4 5]
 [5 1]
 [5 2]
 [5 3]
 [5 4]
 [5 5]] (20, 2)
[[2 3]
 [3 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 2]
 [4 3]]
```

`

```
#to find nearest neighbor
from scipy.spatial import distance
Y = distance.cdist(minority_points, majority_points, 'euclidean')

K = np.argsort(Y)
print (Y)
print ("Ordered data: \n", K)
Y.sort()
print ("After short: \n", Y)
#result
[[2.23606798 1.41421356 1.         1.41421356 2.23606798 2.
  1.         1.         2.         2.23606798 1.41421356 2.23606798
  2.82842712 2.23606798 2.82842712 3.60555128 3.16227766 3.
  3.16227766 3.60555128]
 [2.82842712 2.23606798 2.         2.23606798 2.82842712 2.23606798
  1.41421356 1.41421356 2.23606798 2.         1.         2.
  2.23606798 1.41421356 2.23606798 2.82842712 2.23606798 2.
  2.23606798 2.82842712]
 [3.60555128 2.82842712 2.23606798 2.         2.23606798 3.16227766
  2.23606798 1.         1.41421356 3.         2.         1.
  3.16227766 1.         1.41421356 3.60555128 2.82842712 2.23606798
  2.         2.23606798]
 [3.16227766 3.         3.16227766 3.60555128 4.24264069 2.23606798
  2.         2.82842712 3.60555128 1.41421356 1.         3.16227766
  1.         2.         3.         1.41421356 1.         1.41421356
  2.23606798 3.16227766]
 [3.60555128 3.16227766 3.         3.16227766 3.60555128 2.82842712
  2.23606798 2.23606798 2.82842712 2.23606798 1.41421356 2.23606798
  2.         1.         2.         2.23606798 1.41421356 1.
  1.41421356 2.23606798]]
Ordered data: 
 [[ 2  6  7  1  3 10  5  8  0 13 11  9  4 12 14 17 16 18 15 19]
 [10  6  7 13  9  2 17 11  1  3  5  8 18 12 14 16  0  4 15 19]
 [ 7 11 13  8 14  3 18 10 19  2  4 17  6  1 16  9 12  5 15  0]
 [16 10 12  9 17 15  6 13  5 18  7  1 14  0  2 11 19  8  3  4]
 [17 13 16 10 18 14 12  9 15 11 19  7  6  5  8  2  3  1  4  0]]
After short: 
 [[1.         1.         1.         1.41421356 1.41421356 1.41421356
  2.         2.         2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798
  2.23606798 2.82842712 2.82842712 3.         3.16227766 3.16227766
  3.60555128 3.60555128]
 [1.         1.41421356 1.41421356 1.41421356 2.         2.
  2.         2.         2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798
  2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798 2.82842712 2.82842712
  2.82842712 2.82842712]
 [1.         1.         1.         1.41421356 1.41421356 2.
  2.         2.         2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798
  2.23606798 2.82842712 2.82842712 3.         3.16227766 3.16227766
  3.60555128 3.60555128]
 [1.         1.         1.         1.41421356 1.41421356 1.41421356
  2.         2.         2.23606798 2.23606798 2.82842712 3.
  3.         3.16227766 3.16227766 3.16227766 3.16227766 3.60555128
  3.60555128 4.24264069]
 [1.         1.         1.41421356 1.41421356 1.41421356 2.
  2.         2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798
  2.23606798 2.82842712 2.82842712 3.         3.16227766 3.16227766
  3.60555128 3.60555128]]
```

I want to get the 3-nearest neighbors of each points in minority_points to majority_points and keeps the value of its array and the rest are removed.

This is the ilustration:

1. [before resampling/original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSFVm.png)
2. [after resampling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8veVf.png)

The red points are minority examples, and the blue points are majority examples. So, each minority class calculate its, for example, 3 nearest neighbors from majority. And then the algorithm removed some points which aren't the nearest neighbors.

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: which part that you dont understand? @AkshaySehgal

Comment: How is your data stored? Do you have any code yet? Demonstrating approaches that you have already attempted is integral to asking a good question.

Comment: i added it @Acoop

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've gotten pretty far, and you need some help moving forward. One issue with the way you've gone about sorting the distances. You first create an array of the distances, and then you sort them, but in so doing you lose the contextual information for each distance. You have all the distances, and you have them sorted, but you don't know which points they apply to. This step seem unnecessary to me, and you can just stop with `K` which is the indices of the items in place (not losing the contextual information) while having information about their sorted position. If you take a look at `K`, you may notice that it is a 5x20 matrix, and given the shape of your `majority_points` and `minoirty_points`, (20x2 and 5x2 respectively) this indicates that `K` is a 2D matrix with each row the indices of the sorted distance between a given `n` `minority_point` all the `m` `majority_point`s.

Let's look at an example. The first row in `K` is

```
[ 2  6  7  1  3 10  5  8  0 13 11  9  4 12 14 17 16 18 15 19]
```

this would mean that for the first `minority_point` `[2, 3]` the closest majority points are at index 2, 6, 7, 1, 3 etc. in that order which turns out to be `[1, 3]` `[2, 2]` `[2, 4]` `[1, 2]` etc. in that order. If you take a look, the first 3 are the shortest distance, just 1 unit apart from the `minority_point` in question. (The first vertically, the second two horizontally.) (Note that the sort algorithm places both the closest, but also the *first*, items as they appear in the input array. So index 2 comes before 6 or 7, even though they are all the same distance.)

So all you need to do is create a new array, copying the items at the first 3 indices for each row in K. This is the same thing as saying the 3 closest `majority_points` for each of the `minority_points`.

In numpy conventions this means taking a view of the `majority_points` array (instead of copying the whole thing.) The following line should work (I tested it):

```
majority_points[K[:,0:3]]
```

This means that you grab the elements from `K` (`K[]`) from all rows (the first dimension, before the comma, all being just the `:`,) and the first 3 elements from the second dimension. Those are the indices that you would like to grab from `majority_points`.

The output for me looks like:

```
[[[1 3]
  [2 2]
  [2 4]]

 [[3 2]
  [2 2]
  [2 4]]

 [[2 4]
  [3 5]
  [4 4]]

 [[5 2]
  [3 2]
  [4 1]]

 [[5 3]
  [4 4]
  [5 2]]]
```